# Why isn't my path closing in core graphics?

Tags: core-graphics, objective-c++

This is my code for drawing a polygon. It works but doesn't close or fill.

```
CGContextBeginPath(DrawContext);
for(int i=0;i<sides-1;i++) {
  CGContextMoveToPoint(DrawContext, getRealPos(i)->getX(), getRealPos(i)->getY());
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(DrawContext, getRealPos(i+1)->getX(), getRealPos(i+1)->getY());
}
CGContextClosePath(DrawContext);
CGContextStrokePath(DrawContext);
CGContextFillPath(DrawContext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you are using `CGContextMoveToPoint` in loop. `CGContextMoveToPoint` is used to set the current point and start a new sub path. In other words, just to define a starting point of a path.

And `CGContextAddLineToPoint` will add the line from this point to the specified point and also sets the current point to the endpoint of the line segment. So you don't have to use `CGContextMoveToPoint` every time after drawing one line. Moreover, when you use `CGContextMoveToPoint`, it starts altogether a new sub path. So basically you are closing only one sub path in your code and thats the last one.

So use `CGContextMoveToPoint` only once outside the `for` loop and then continue drawing using `CGContextAddLineToPoint`. And at last close it using `CGContextClosePath`.

For further understanding refer docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextMoveToPoint

Comment: It closes but it is still not filling.

Comment: If I put CGContextFillPath first it will just fill, but if I put CGContextStrokePath first it will just stroke. Shouldn't I be able to do both?

Comment: It should do both. Its difficult to tell without looking at your code. So if you can post your modified code, I will have a look at it.

Comment: CGContextBeginPath(DrawContext);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(DrawContext, getRealPos(0)->getX(), getRealPos(0)->getY());
            for(int i=0;i<sides-1;i++) {
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(DrawContext, getRealPos(i+1)->getX(), getRealPos(i+1)->getY());
            }
            CGCOntext
            CGContextClosePath(DrawContext);
            CGContextFillPath(DrawContext);

Comment: As far as this drawing code is concerned, it is correct. I think there is something wrong with your remaining code. You should try drawing a very small and simple shape using the approach I told in my answer to confirm that there is something wrong with the remaining code.